# Separating Axis Theorem - Python Implementation from Cartesian Points

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, separating-axis-theorem

Im trying to implement SAT in Python and can't seem to get it working. There is a lot on information on the net but none of it seems to explain the code (at least in a way I can understand) and how to apply SAT if you have points on the cartesian plane.

In my problem, I have two rectangles (which may or may not be on an angle) stored as a list of x and y coordinates.

I.e. I have two lists r1, r2 which contain [x1, y1], [x2, ..... [x4, y4] for each of the two rectangles.

How can I implement code in Python to apply Separating Axis theorem to determine collision?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have (tried) ? What the input of that code is, what the expected output of that code is, and what the actual output of the code is ?

Comment: All I have with me is code to randomly generate the two rectangles and store them in the lists r1, r2 as described in the question. 

I can't seem to understand the SAT information I am reading to implement the code. 
From what I understand I need to create vectors to replace the points, create perpendicular axes then I'm sort of lost, but I can't even get the points into vectors at the moment.

EDIT: Just thought I would note my code is also printing the rectangles to the screen.